# How do I solve a problem decoding json accessed by a URL using server-sent events?

Tags: php, json, server-sent-events

I have been working on retrieving metadata associated Icecast streams and thought I had the problem solved because things went perfectly using the below HTML, JavaScript and PHP snippets of code (augmented by CSS for scrolling the parsed data) on the local machine.

On a live, public-facing server I got some CORS errors that seemed to have been fixed by using access control headers. However, with that settled, I now seem unable to access the Icecast xsl file with the php json decoder. After reading around the Web I resorted to curl when file_get_contents (which worked properly on the local server) retrieved nothing.

The Icecast subdomain server is behind an Apache reverse proxy, the stream plays through to the www and the xsl file is accessible in a browser from the Web as seen in the json output below.

The  Firefox console shows a 200 response for the javascript accessing the php file but only prints out the periods (full stops) where interpreted objects should be. Permission on the PHP is 755 so I assume it can do its job.

How can I determine where the bottleneck is and from the code below, can a problem that needs correcting or enhancing be identified?

The HTML:

```
<div id="scroll-container">
  <span class="scroll-text" id="scroll-text"><span>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
//Get the stream meta from xml
messages = new Array();
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  var source = new EventSource("https://www.example.com/radio/js/json.php");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    if (messages.length == 2) messages.splice(-1, 1);
                    messages.splice(0, 0, event.data);
                    document.getElementById("scroll-text").innerHTML = messages.join("<br />");
                };
            } else {
                document.getElementById("scroll-text").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
            }
```

The PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Accept: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://listen.abengnews.com/status-json.xsl');
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//$json = file_get_contents('https://listen.example.com/status-json.xsl');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$retry = 15000;
echo "data:{$obj->icestats->source->server_name}.\nretry:{$retry}\n ";
echo "data:{$obj->icestats->source->genre}. Now playing:\nretry:{$retry}\n";
echo "data:{$obj->icestats->source->title}.\nretry:{$retry}\n";
echo "data:{$obj->icestats->source->server_description}\n\nretry:{$retry}\n\n";
//$retry = 10000;
flush();
```

The json retrieved by directly loading the URL in a browser:

```
{
  "icestats": {
    "admin": "me@example.com",
    "host": "listen.example.com",
    "location": "Mississaauga, Ontario",
    "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.4",
    "server_start": "Sun, 21 May 2023 22:35:55 -0400",
    "server_start_iso8601": "2023-05-21T22:35:55-0400",
    "source": {
      "audio_info": "bitrate=128;samplerate=22050;channels=2",
      "bitrate": 128,
      "channels": 2,
      "genre": "News, Reggae",
      "listener_peak": 5,
      "listeners": 1,
      "listenurl": "http://listen.example.com/sounds.mp3",
      "samplerate": 22050,
      "server_description": "News and reggae",
      "server_name": "Example Radio",
      "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
      "server_url": "listen.example.com",
      "stream_start": "Mon, 22 May 2023 11:01:16 -0400",
      "stream_start_iso8601": "2023-05-22T11:01:16-0400",
      "title": "Burning Spear - Foggy Road",
      "dummy": null
    }
  }
}
```

Response in the console:

```
XHRGET
https://www.example.com/radio/js/json.php
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 130295ms]

1 data:.
2 retry:15000
3 data:. Now playing:
4 retry:15000
5 data:.
6 retry:15000
7 data:
8
9 retry:15000
10
11
```

Comment: _"The json retrieved by directly loading the URL in a browser:"_ - and what has your _script_ actually received? Did `$json` contain the same - or something else perhaps, like an error message maybe?

Comment: It retrieved nothing. What's reproduced in the last block above is from the console. If it had parsed the .xsl it would have output where the "station" is and the currently playing mp3's title.

Answer (score 0):

> `$obj = json_decode($json);`

I think the problem is with what you are assuming is in json.  If you did a print_r($json) just before the above, it would help your troubleshooting.

The output you see is consistent with `$obj->icestats->source` not being set (some guesses as to why, and what to do about it, are below). So check for that existing before pushing out your SSE response; if it isn't set you might want to push out an error message instead, and log what is in `$obj`.

---

Here is what I see, trying that URL.

```
$ curl https://listen.abengnews.com/status-json.xsl | grep jq
{
  "icestats": {
    "admin": "mark.lee@abengnews.com",
    "host": "listen.abengnews.com",
    "location": "Mississaauga, Ontario",
    "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.4",
    "server_start": "Tue, 23 May 2023 09:53:36 -0400",
    "server_start_iso8601": "2023-05-23T09:53:36-0400",
    "dummy": null
  }
}
```

(The `jq` command is not important, it is just to pretty-print the JSON.)

I.e. no "source".

If you see something different from your browser window my guess would be is that you have a cookie (maybe you have previously logged into that site). Or it could be IP-based (if they are in different countries, that might explain why it worked on your local setup, but not on the production server).

If it is a cookie, and you can work out from your browser what it is, you can send that with curl, but you can also go back to using file_get_contents by using [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php). If it requires a login, that is a bit more work, but still doable.

If an IP restriction you will need to set the server up in a different data centre. Or discuss with the service you are querying.

Comment: The output you retrieved was when nothing was being streamed, ie, the "source" was down.

Comment: Addendum: I beautified my browser output of the xsl for reabability.

Comment: I added a small bit at the top of my answer to emphasize the important bit.

Comment: see my first comment: the "source" was down when you tried. Nothing was being streamed, hence no `$obj->icestats->source`. It was up three hours ago when you edited your answer though. I am digging deeper into CORS and PHP.

Comment: My edit was to clarify that all the evidence points to that when your script returns blanks it means it is not receiving `source`.

Comment: Got ya. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the issue. A front facing AJAX script, sans PHP, plays as expected but that defeats the purpose of eliminating multiple requests to the server rather than sending info to the browser.

Comment: I have deployed the server on the same machine as the virtual host using the same domain name and the stream and data retrieval seem to be working as expected but varies with where it is accessed from. Looking keenly at the situation, it's a complex of the SSL cert/CORS and the fact that the Mixxx streaming client does not have built in support for SSL, so that the configured https://www.abengnews.com:8000/sounds.mp3 does not play the stream, the secure link https://www.abengnews.com:8443/sounds.mp3 is accessible to players. I will continue the hunt for real answers.